# Giving a user access to a google analytics property

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to give a user access to a certain property without access to the rest of website in google analytics. For example we have a property for a domain and its subdomain. We want to give a user access to subdomain.website.com property and not website.com. How would you do that in google analytics?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible (provided the user has a valid Google Account). It is such a common use case that it is basically [used as an example in the documentation of the Google Analytics Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/user-management) (except the example connects the user to a data view (profile), so if you want to give access to a property you'd have to use [propertyUserLinks](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webpropertyUserLinks/insert) instead of [profileUserLinks](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profileUserLinks)).